# How to perform a conditional grouping in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, grouping

I have a maintenance/ driving data set on a set of truck inventory
I have to derive key issues on the maintenance and group them together 
the logic provided by the customer is as follows:

> 1. if there were less than 3 trips between main works  and
> 2. if the key word overlaps (More than 1 key word is possible)
>      then group them together.

Here is a sample with a desired output (Group column) based on key words, truck id, in/out:

```
    data =     {'Truck':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
    'Date':['1/1/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/5/2019', '1/6/2019', '1/7/2019', '1/8/2019', '1/9/2019', '1/10/2019', '1/11/2019', '1/12/2019', '1/12/2019', '1/18/2019', '1/19/2019', '1/20/2019', '1/21/2019'],
     'Description': ['need oil change', 'flat tire pump', 'filter replaced', 'oil filled', 'truck on the road', 'flat tire replace', 'nail in tire', 'fix tire', 'truck on the road', 'truck on the road', 'tire replace', 'oil leak', 'replaced ring due to leak', 'truck on the road', 'truck on the road', 'truck on the road', 'replace filter due to leak'
],
 'Key_Words': ['oil', 'tire', 'filter, replace', 'oil', '', 'tire', 'tire', 'tire', '', '', 'tire', 'oil, leak', 'leak, replace', '', '', '', 'filter,replace,leak'], 
'Type_of_Work': ['main', 'main', 'assist', 'assist', '', 'main', 'assist', 'assist', '', '', 'main', 'main', 'assist', '', '', '', 'main'], 
'In_Out':['in', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'trip', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'trip', 'trip', 'in', 'in', 'in', 'trip', 'trip', 'trip', 'in'],
'Group':['1', '2', '3', '1', '', '2', '2', '2', '', '', '4', '5', '5', '', '', '', '6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I've tried to allocate 'main' work and group the assist under, but seems like sometimes assis is not related to main work, and some times it belongs to an earlier work started. 
I do not have a work code to track the work relations. Only key words would help.
I know how to calcultate the trip count between a two given main works, but I'm not sure how to keep a running total. As long as the number of trips from the last maintenance is less than three and the issue persists - I need to treat it as the same issue and on-going maintenance.

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: @yatu - the Group column is the expected output

Comment: I think the `there were less than 3 trips between main works` means a normal `groupby` isn't going to work. Needs to be something more like a rolling or a loop.